# Ajax %-wildcard URL giving 404 error when setting a parameter

Tags: ajax, routes

I have a page with a dropdown. When you click on that dropdown that content is loaded by Ajax. I would like to do the same for the **Breadcrumb**, so I created an Ajax-URL in my module:

```
function selectexamfeature_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['selectexamfeature/ajax-replace-breadcrumb/%'] = array(
      'title' => 'Ajax-Callback for replacing breadcrumb',
      'page callback' => 'selectexamfeature_ajax_callback',
      'page arguments' => array(2),
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function selectexamfeature_ajax_callback($url){
  $commands = array();
    // later on the $url will be used here for generating the breadcrumb html
  $ret = $url;
  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('.page-breadcrumb', $ret);
  $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  ajax_deliver($page);
}
```

and in my Javascript code I have:

```
  var custom_settings = {};
  custom_settings.url = '/selectexamfeature/ajax-replace-breadcrumb/SOMELINKASSTRING';
  custom_settings.keypress = false;
  custom_settings.prevent = false;
  Drupal.ajax['custom_ajax_action'] = new Drupal.ajax(null, $(document.body), custom_settings);

  Drupal.behaviors.selectexamfeature_ajax_replace_breadcrumb = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $( "#edit-field-text-grade-tid" ).change(function() {
        // the event...
      });
    }
  };
```

So at the end I want to get the `SOMELINKASSTRING` in my `$ret` variable. But for now I just get a 404 error all the time:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. 
>   HTTP response code: 404 
>   Debugg information follows: /selectexamfeature/ajax-replace-breadcrumb/SOMELINKASSTRING Statustext: Not Found...

I believe the issue is in the wildcard section. Somehow it does not replace it correctly.

If I leave the `%` away and also the `SOMELINKASSTRING` it works without issues. But I for sure need the parameter to know which page is requested.

Also watch this awesome [article](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) but it did not help either.

Comment: Is the dropdown part of a standard Drupal Form API form or is it custom?

Comment: Not it's something custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with drupal hooks. So I use an already existing Ajax trigger.

```
function selectexamfeature_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'breadcrumb' => array(
      'template' => 'breadcrumb',
    ),
  );
}
```

and

```
function selectexamfeature_views_ajax_data_alter(&$commands, $view) {
 ...
 // building the url variable
 ...
 $vars = array();
 themename_generate_breadcrumb($vars);
 $markup = theme('breadcrumb', array('breadcrumb' => drupal_get_breadcrumb()));
 $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('div.page-breadcrumb', $markup);
}
```

This works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

If the form is part of a standard Drupal form, you can use Drupal's built in AJAX system. There is a detailed explanation here: [Ajax Forms in Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/752056). Basically it should look like this.

```
function hook_some_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // Create a frop down
  $form['some_select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => $default,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'some_ajax_callback', // This is the php function to be called
      'wrapper' => 'some_wrapper', // The javascript #id to put content in.
      'method' => 'replace', // Content placement option
    ),
  );

  // Result contents container
  $form['some_wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#id' => 'some_wrapper',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );
}
```

And for the PHP callback

```
function some_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  // Fetch the value AJAX gave us.
  $value = $form_state['values']['some_select'];

  // Recreate the wrapper as we overwrite the old one.
  $form['some_wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#id' => 'some_wrapper',
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );

  // Append the value of the drop down to it.
  $form['some_wrapper']['value'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => check_plain($value);
  );
  // Return everything to Javascript.
  return $form['some_wrapper']
}
```

This allows you to pass form values to PHP for processing.

Comment: No it's not a form, it's just a dropdown and does not use form features.

Comment: Then this isn't of much value, sorry.

Comment: No problem, maybe helpful for someone else. :)